# Full Unreal engine API support in Python?

Tags: c++, python, unreal-5, api

I'm a newbie to the Unreal engine, and I've seen that there is very little documentation and examples of Python in the Unreal engine, so I'd like to ask if, leaving out the gameplay functionality, we can expose the rest of the interfaces to Python via pybind11, and then program the Python to handle it.